# Use macro/newcommand for attributes

Tags: macros

How would one define a `newcommand` so that it can be used for attributes?

I have `\somecommand` which I can pass attributes, for example `color=black` in square brackets.
Now I want to have a `newcommand` to do something like this:

```
\newcommand{\anewcommand}{color=black}

\begin{document}
    \somecommand[\anewcommand]
\end{document}
```

Although the `anewcommand` holds the same value as I would pass by typing it out, it doesn't work and tells me that my attributes are not defined.

Well. The `\somecommand` is actually the `ganttbar` command of the [gantt.sty](http://www.martin-kumm.de/tex/gantt.sty) package. I want to have `\newcommand{\person}{color=black}` and then pass `\person` to `\ganttbar[\person]`. hope this clarifies it more.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{gantt}

\newcommand{\person}{color=black}

\begin{document}
    \begin{gantt}[xunitlength=0.8cm,fontsize=\small,titlefontsize=\small,drawledgerline=true]{2}{7} %{# of tasks}{# of slots}
        \begin{ganttitle}
            \titleelement{week 1}{7}
        \end{ganttitle}
        \ganttbar[color=NavyBlue]{localization}{3}{3} % this works
        \ganttbar[\person]{Bla}{1}{1} % this doesn't
    \end{gantt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Depending on the definition of `\somecommand`, `\anewcommand` may be used directly or expanded. We need more context to give a good answer.

Comment: It clarifies it more but I find it still confusing and in any case, can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: where did you get gantt.sty from I didn't see it on ctan only pst-gantt and pgfgantt

Comment: It's a package by Martin Krumm. Don't know why it isn't listed on ctan. Pgfgantt uses gantt.sty though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping the command with `{}` makes your MWE compilable.

However, I can't offer you insight into the inner workings. Maybe somebody else can help out here.

EDIT:

`\person{}` made it compilable, but as cherrung pointed out in the comments, it doesn't really solve the issue.

As a simple workaround, I'd define only the actual color-argument as a variable:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{gantt}

\newcommand{\person}{green}

\begin{document}
    \begin{gantt}[xunitlength=0.8cm,fontsize=\small,titlefontsize=\small,drawledgerline=true]{2}{7} %{# of tasks}{# of slots}
        \begin{ganttitle}
            \titleelement{week 1}{7}
        \end{ganttitle}
        \ganttbar[color=NavyBlue]{localization}{3}{3} % this works
        \ganttbar[color=\person]{Bla}{1}{1} % this works as well
    \end{gantt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. And here I was thinking that I've tried every possible combination with `{}`. Well... I'm really interested in why it works.

EDIT: Oh. Just noticed that it doesn't work. It just uses the standard color, which is black. Kinda stupid, because I defined `person` with `black`.

Comment: @cherrung: That's correct. I didn't really check for that. I edited the answer to offer you an actual fix.

Comment: Not as elegant, but I guess best solution I can get for now.